# nested array for multiple row insert is getting stringify with sequelize nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

As per some answers i am using this type of array to insert multiple rows in mysql

```
[ [ 252456, 1, 55, '0' ],
[ 357083, 1, 56, '0' ],
[ 316493, 1, 57, '0' ] ]
```

so after this expected result was

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (252456,1,55,'0'), (357083,1,56,'0'), (316493,1,57,'0')
```

but actual query what is running is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES 252456,1,55,'0',357083,1,56,'0',316493,1,57,'0'
```

Can anyone help with he problem?? below is my code snippet

```
let get_rows = await db.sequelize.query("select col1, col1, col3, '0' as col4 from table1 where (condition1 = '3' || condition2 = '4') and condition3 = '0';", {replacements: [], type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});

    if(get_rows && get_rows.length){
        let insert_rows = get_rows.map(x => Object.values(x));

        await db.sequelize.query("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ?;", {replacements: [insert_rows], type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT});
    };
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to insert the data?

Comment: Most likely the data should be an array of objects, like `[ { col1: '1', col2: '2', ... }, ... ]`

Comment: @Kristian Earlier i was trying array of objects only but found some answers on SO to do it like this. Also adding my code in question.

Comment: Oh, the issue might also be that you are double nesting `insert_rows`. Try using `await db.sequelize.query("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ?;", {replacements: insert_rows, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT});`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you building query manually string by string, if you are using a ORM (Sequelize) for that ?

Try [`Model.bulkCreate`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

To use the `bulkCreate` first prepare your data as follows

```
const rawData = [
  [ 252456, 1, 55, '0' ],
  [ 357083, 1, 56, '0' ],
  [ 316493, 1, 57, '0' ] 
];

const convertedData = rawData.map(arrObj => {
  return {
    col1: arrObj[0],
    col2: arrObj[1],
    col3: arrObj[2],
    col4: arrObj[3]
  }
})
```

Then just feed it to your Sequelize model as follows

```
await Table1Model.bulkCreate(convertedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9050)

The feature has been implemented and merged in [this pull request](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/9054/files), perhaps you need to update your sequelize version?

If unable to update, check [this post](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9050#issuecomment-365846215) from same issue (copying for historical reasons):

```
let data = [ [ 252456, 1, 55, '0' ],
[ 357083, 1, 56, '0' ],
[ 316493, 1, 57, '0' ] ];

db.query(`INSERT INTO product (a, b) VALUES ${data.map(a => '(?)').join(',')};`, {
    replacements: data,
    type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
});
```

This will automatically create placeholders for all array items so they will be grouped correctly.

Comment: Do i need to upgrade sequelize for above solution also as after your solution this query is running `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ${data.map(a=> '(252456, 1, 55, '0', 357083, 1, 56, '0', 316493, 1, 57, '0')').join(',')}`

Comment: Updated my answer, you don't need to update for that solution

Comment: But query executing after this solution is not correct as i mentioned in above comment.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: @pakut2 just started using models with this array